# Function Call That Checks For Input Correctness From Text File - C++

Tags: c++, ifstream

How could I check a text file if the data underneath "INSERT_EMPLOYEE" is enough to be inputted into my "insertEmployee" function? (Example: right  number, type    of  arguments,  or  checking for    argument    boundaries) Also, if the input  is  invalid format, I do    not want to perform the operation, but rather just skip to the next operation.

My text file:

```
INSERT_EMPLOYEE
12345
John
Smith
60000
35

INSERT_EMPLOYEE
Chris
Evans
70000

INSERT_EMPLOYEE
34567
Michael
Carter
50500
25

PRINT_ROSTER
```

My main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int id, salary, hours;
    employeeList list = employeeList();
    string line, firstName, lastName;

    ifstream employeeFile;
    employeeFile.open("employeeFile.txt");
    while(getline(employeeFile, line)) {
        if (line == "INSERT_EMPLOYEE") {
            employeeFile >> id >> firstName >> lastName >> salary >> hours;
            list.insertEmployee(id, firstName, lastName, salary, hours);
        }
        if (line == "PRINT_ROSTER") {
            list.printRoster();
        }
    employeeFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You do that by using `std::getline()` and validating the input yourself. The `>>` formatted input extraction operator works great when the input is valid. If it's not, you have a big mess on your hands that's going to be difficult to unravel. Therefore, if input validation is required, don't use `>>`. End of story.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik That makes perfect sense, thank you!

Comment: grammar note: "_inputted_ into my "insertEmployee" function? ".  try the more formal "passed by value to insertEmployee() function", or pass by reference, or perhaps 'send to insertEmployee() function"   Or pick a synonym of the proper tense: put in, load, insert; key in, type in, enter; code, store.  'inputted' is a past tense description of something your code has not yet done.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to parse/validate input according to a grammar, consider using a parser.

Writing parsers is tedious, though. So consider using a parser generater. Since you're writing C++, consider one that you compile on the fly, like with Boost Spirit:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/64d0ef23b116b851)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi_match.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

struct Employee {
    unsigned id;
    std::string firstname, surname;
    double salary;
    unsigned hours;
};

static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Employee const& emp) {
    return os << "Employee (" 
        << emp.id << " " 
        << emp.firstname << " " 
        << emp.surname << " " 
        << emp.salary << " " 
        << emp.hours << ")";
}

struct employeeList {
    std::vector<Employee> employees;

    void printRoster() const {
        std::cout << "\nRoster:\n";
        for (auto& emp : employees)
            std::cout << emp << "\n";
    }
};

namespace parser {
    using namespace boost::spirit::qi;
    auto const INSERT = copy(uint_ >> eol >> +graph >> eol >> +graph >> eol >> double_ >> eol >> uint_);
}

int main() {
    employeeList list = employeeList();
    std::string line, firstName, lastName;

    std::ifstream input("employeeFile.txt");
    input.unsetf(std::ios::skipws);

    std::string command;
    while (getline(input, command)) {
        if (command == "INSERT_EMPLOYEE") {
            Employee emp;

            if (input >> qi::phrase_match(parser::INSERT, qi::blank, emp.id, emp.firstname, emp.surname, emp.salary, emp.hours)) {
                std::cout << "Added " << emp << "\n";
                list.employees.push_back(emp);
            }
            else {
                std::cout << "Ignoring invalid INSERT_EMPLOYEE command\n";
                input.clear();
                input.ignore(1024, '\n');
            }
        }
        if (command == "PRINT_ROSTER") {
            list.printRoster();
        }

        // skip any non-valid lines until empty line
        while (getline(input, command)) {
            if (command.empty())
                break;
            //else std::cout << "Skipping over input '" << command << "'\n";
        }
    }
}
```

For the given sample input it prints:

```
Added Employee (12345 John Smith 60000 35)
Ignoring invalid INSERT_EMPLOYEE command
Added Employee (34567 Michael Carter 50500 25)

Roster:
Employee (12345 John Smith 60000 35)
Employee (34567 Michael Carter 50500 25)
```